# Show array builder to list view?

Tags: android, arrays, listview, builder

I want work with array and `listView`. How can we show a value of an array with builder to `listvView`?

this is my code:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
String a = "";
  JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){
  JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
  a=json.getString("ID");//+" - "+json.getString("post")+"\n"+"\n"; 
builder.append(a);
builder.append(" ");    
}
```

We get values from external database.

Comment: Create an array of strings. Add strings to array. Add array to ArrayAdapter.

Comment: there is no array in your code.